# HTMX parsing JSON response issue

Tags: django, htmx

I have a page that posts some data to the Django back-end and JSON response is returned. I have an issue parsing this using templates.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
    <div class="card-body">
            <form>
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <label class="input-group-text">Command</label>
                    <select class="form-select" name="run_show_command" id="run_show_command">
                        <option selected disabled>Choose...</option>
                        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:1">show ip interface brief</option>
                        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:2">show interfaces description</option>
                        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:3">show ip arp</option>
                        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:4">show ip route</option>
                        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:5">show ip cef</option>
                        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:6">show version</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" hx-post="{% url 'inventory:device_run_command' %}" hx-target="#command_output" mustache-template="m_template" hx-indicator="#loader_bars">
                        <i class="fas fa-terminal"></i> Run
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" hx-ext="client-side-templates" id="command_output">
                <img id="loader_bars" class="htmx-indicator" alt="Loading..." src="{% static 'images/loaders/bars.svg' %}"/>
                <template id="m_template" type="text/mustache">
                    {% for data in dataset %}
                    {% for key, value in data.items %}
                        <li>{{ key }} {{ value }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JSON:

```
 [{ "intf": "GigabitEthernet1", "ipaddr": "10.10.20.48", "status": "up", "proto": "up" }, { "intf": "GigabitEthernet2", "ipaddr": "unassigned", "status": "administratively down", "proto": "down" }, { "intf": "GigabitEthernet3", "ipaddr": "unassigned", "status": "administratively down", "proto": "down" }, { "intf": "Loopback1", "ipaddr": "10.10.10.100", "status": "up", "proto": "up" }, { "intf": "Loopback123", "ipaddr": "unassigned", "status": "up", "proto": "up" }, { "intf": "Loopback510", "ipaddr": "50.10.10.10", "status": "up", "proto": "up" }, { "intf": "Loopback511", "ipaddr": "51.10.10.10", "status": "up", "proto": "up" }, { "intf": "Loopback512", "ipaddr": "52.10.10.10", "status": "up", "proto": "up" }, { "intf": "Loopback666", "ipaddr": "6.6.6.6", "status": "up", "proto": "up" } ]
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no, i'm expecting output to be parsed as per the template but it's rendered raw (as is in the JSON example).

Comment: Just looking at the examples in the HTMX documentation, I think you need to move `hx-ext="client-side-templates"` up higher in the HTML, like on the `<div class="card-body">` element.

Comment: I'll give that a go but I've tried everything up to this point and nothing has worked, will try again :)

Comment: OK so I moved it to the upper DIV (card & card body) no output is being displayed at all then :/

Comment: I wonder if it is because you are returning a JSON array instead of a JSON object. I can't find any examples of that in the HTMX docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Django templates on the frontend like you tried in the `<template>` tag. HTMX supports 3 javascript templating library: [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) and [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/). The closest one to Django is nunjucks, which is inspired by Jinja2, which is inspired by Django Templates, so it will be more-or-less familiar.

So first, don't forget to add the HTMX extension and nunjucks library to your JS bundle, or directly into the HTML base template, e.g.:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1/dist/ext/client-side-templates.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nunjucks/3.0.1/nunjucks.min.js"
   integrity="sha512-IIuR+Zp8wvP0dxNcSsRPoL7SXzP1kGmosDtcU7f6cPObZ9F5Ze/icFSRH/SqigP468jGwDm2XOE0/gSGm/cTBw=="
   crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The updated template:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group mb-3" hx-ext="client-side-templates">
      <label class="input-group-text">Command</label>
      <select class="form-select" name="run_show_command" id="run_show_command">
        <option selected disabled>Choose...</option>
        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:1">show ip interface brief</option>
        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:2">show interfaces description</option>
        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:3">show ip arp</option>
        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:4">show ip route</option>
        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:5">show ip cef</option>
        <option value="{{ data.version.id }}:6">show version</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" hx-post="{% url 'inventory:device_run_command' %}"
        hx-target="#command_output" nunjucks-template="m_template" hx-indicator="#loader_bars">
        <i class="fas fa-terminal"></i> Run
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div id="command_output">
      <img id="loader_bars" class="htmx-indicator" alt="Loading..." src="{% static 'images/loaders/bars.svg' %}" />
    </div>
    <template id="m_template">
    {% verbatim %}
      <ul>
        {% for item in items %}
        {% for key, value in item %}
        <li>{{ key }} {{ value }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endverbatim %}
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I moved the `hx-ext` attribute the the button's parent div, otherwise it won't work. Nunjucks has quite [similar syntax](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html), but for example, we don't need to append `.items` in the nested loop.

**Edit:** I missed a very important detail previously: since nunjucks and DTL has very similar syntax, we have to embed the nunjucks template in a [`{% verbatim %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) block that tells Django to just ignore it. Otherwise it gets evaluated by Django at the backend instead of nunjucks at the frontend.

Furthermore you need to have a top level key in your JSON file, that will be the key in the first for loop.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "intf": "GigabitEthernet1",
            "ipaddr": "10.10.20.48",
            "status": "up",
            "proto": "up"
        },
        {
            "intf": "GigabitEthernet2",
            "ipaddr": "unassigned",
            "status": "administratively down",
            "proto": "down"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also just found this: https://dev.to/marcusatlocalhost/handle-json-api-results-in-htmx-f46 
so when working with nunjucks <template> tag is not used but rather <script>.

Comment: Well, you may have a different issue, or implemented my suggestion incorrectly. I created a [jsFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/kacmt9wo/) where you can see my suggestion is correct and produces exactly what you want. The mentioned nunjucks method is just an example. If you look at the HTMX extension's [source code](https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1/dist/ext/client-side-templates.js), you see that HTMX can extract the template code from anywhere then it calls the respective nunjucks render method, so it's working with `<template>` as well.

Comment: I have replicated it as per your advise, you can have a look: https://github.com/sngx13/net_autom8/blob/master/templates/inventory/device_detailed_information.html
Can see returned JSON data correctly in Chrome debug but nothing is displayed on the page. If I "break" the template e.g nunjucks-template="#cmd_output_template" (note the hash). Output is rendered unformated but I'm getting the following in the console:
DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '##cmd_output_template' is not a valid selector. So that would suggest something is wrong with template?

Comment: Are you sure that you return the correct JSON data? I think you have an indentation error in [`cli_command_runner`](https://github.com/sngx13/net_autom8/blob/17ac67900672624807736f926f7ddc5553048c9e/tasks/scripts/device_run_cmd.py#L25). You update the `platform` variable, but then you have to go back to the main function block level.

Comment: Otherwise your template modification is correct, I just tested it locally (replaced `hx-post` with `hx-get="local.json"`) and it was working fine, rendering the list as intended.

Comment: Python side is correct. I'm getting a response successfully, if I don't use the template it is displayed but unformated. I'm getting back from Django backend:
{
    "items": [
        {
            "intf": "GigabitEthernet1",
            "ipaddr": "10.10.20.48",
            "status": "up",
            "proto": "up"
        },
        {
            "intf": "GigabitEthernet2",
            "ipaddr": "10.255.254.1",
            "status": "up",
            "proto": "up"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: OK so i went further and changed my "hx-post" to "hx-get" with following URL: https://api.npoint.io/a0731487a46fc3565578 which matches my data format. Nothing is displayed :/

Comment: @sngx I'm sorry, I missed a key point. I setup your project locally, and it wasn't working for me neither. Then I realized we need to embed nunjucks template within a `{% verbatim %}` block, otherwise it gets evaluated by Django at the backend. I corrected my example code. Please add these two lines to the template then it should work, finally. The API endpoint throws a 500 error for me, maybe something missing from the repo, I did not debug that further. But with [this JSON](https://api.npoint.io/4de6b8495f386e7cbc25) example, it works for me locally (still requires a `items` top level key).

Comment: Oh man, I love you!!! That's done the trick :)